# MySql Select tableA.column when tableB.column = tableC.colum

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a subway map in my database where every stop of each Line is a row.
If I want to know where my Lines interconnect :

```
mysql> SELECT LineA.stop_id FROM LineA, LineB WHERE LineA.stop_id = LineB.stop_id;
    +---------+
    | stop_id |
    +---------+
    | 1100    |
    | 1300    |
    +---------+
```

How can I join this result to my stations table so i can retrieve the stations name ?

Here the tables :

```
        stations
+----------------+---------+
| name           | stop_id |
+----------------+---------+
| Nation         | 1100    |
| Republic       | 1300    |
| Main_st        | 1065    |
| Airport        | 1204    |
+----------------+---------+

         LineA
+----------------+---------+
| id             | stop_id |
+----------------+---------+
| 1              | 1100    |
| 2              | 1300    |
| 3              | 1204    |
+----------------+---------+

         LineB
+----------------+---------+
| id             | stop_id |
+----------------+---------+
| 1              | 1100    |
| 2              | 1300    |
| 3              | 1265    |
+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Also what if need to check if more than 2 lines interconnect ? I try with something like A.stop_id = B.stop_id = C.stop_id but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to your answer: try this

```
select B.* from (SELECT LineA.stop_id FROM LineA, LineB WHERE LineA.stop_id = LineB.stop_id) as A
INNER JOIN stations as B on A.stop_id=B.stop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM stations as ST 
 LEFT JOIN LineA as LA ON LA.stop_id =ST.stop_id 
 LEFT JOIN LineB as LB ON LB.stop_id =ST.stop_id
```

Comment: It just needed to add WHERE LA.stop_id = LB.stop_id
Thank you.